# merge two queries and having no relation

Tags: sql-server, merge

I am creating a stored procedure in SQL Server, where are 2 different queries select different records but having same table, and both will not have any relation in the query.

Here is my query

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 3
         Players.Player_Name AS 'HomeTeamBatsman',
         PlayerScores.Bat_Runs As 'HomeTeamRuns'        
     FROM 
         PlayerScores
     INNER JOIN
         Players ON PlayerScores.PlayerId = Players.PlayerId
     INNER JOIN
         Teams ON Players.TeamId = Teams.TeamId
     INNER JOIN
         Matches ON PlayerScores.MatchId = Matches.MatchId
     WHERE 
         (Teams.TeamId = 1)
         AND (Matches.MatchId = 1025)
     GROUP BY 
         Players.Player_Name,
         PlayerScores.Bat_Runs
     ORDER BY
         MAX(Bat_Runs) DESC) As HomeTeamBatting,
    (SELECT TOP 3
         Players.Player_Name AS 'OpponentTeamBatsman',
         PlayerScores.Bat_Runs As 'OpponentTeamRuns'     
     FROM 
         PlayerScores
     INNER JOIN
         Players ON PlayerScores.PlayerId = Players.PlayerId
     INNER JOIN
         Teams ON Players.TeamId = Teams.TeamId
     INNER JOIN
         Matches ON PlayerScores.MatchId = Matches.MatchId
     WHERE 
         (Teams.TeamId = 3)
         AND (Matches.MatchId = 1025)
     GROUP BY 
         Players.Player_Name,
         PlayerScores.Bat_Runs
     ORDER BY
         MAX(Bat_Runs) DESC) AS OpponentTeamBatting
END
go
```

It returns the following results, however, I don't want any relation b/t those queries

[image]

What I am expecting:

[image]

Comment: So what *is* the result set you're expecting here? Help us help you and explain your needs please. What you have what now is effectively a `CROSS JOIN`, a Cartesian product, of your 2 result sets.

Comment: _I don't want any relation b/t those queries_ What you mean by b/t? and what is the expected results?

Comment: I would guess, *"b/t"* means "between", @Sami but not a guess I was going to take when editting.

Comment: I am expecting three records form the first query and other 3 from the second  query

Comment: I'm afraid that statement makes no sense. It seems there's a language barrier here. Sample data (by means of DDL (`CREATE`) and DML (`INSERT`) statements) and expected results are going to be very useful if you're struggling to phrase your question in English.

Comment: ok let me try to make you understand, look in the sample result that i have upload already, u can clearly see each HomeTeam player making type of relation here from OpponentTeamPlayer example. Mubashir with Mehmood khan, mubashir again with abid hussain and mubashir with ibrahim khan,,

Comment: Yes, we can see the results you got. What we can't see, however, is what you see in your mind's eye; the volunteers here aren't mind readers. You need to show us what you're after. Like I said; Help us help you.

Comment: I attached my expected result.. Hope i ll get the solution .

Answer (score 3):

At a pure guess, I ***think*** you want `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 3,
           'Home' AS Team,
           P.Player_Name AS Batsman,
           PS.Bat_Runs As Runs  
    FROM PlayerScores PS
         JOIN Players P ON PS.PlayerId = P.PlayerId
         JOIN Teams T ON P.TeamId = T.TeamId
         JOIN Matches M  ON PS.MatchId = M.MatchId
    WHERE T.TeamId = 1
    AND M.MatchId = 1025
    GROUP BY P.Player_Name,
             PS.Bat_Runs
    ORDER BY Bat_Runs DESC --As the GROUP BY is on Bat_Runs, MAX isn't needed
                           --In truth,why is there even a GROUP BY with no aggregation?
) AS Home
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Top 3
           'Away' AS Team,
           P.Player_Name AS Batsman,
           PS.Bat_Runs As Runs
    FROM PlayerScores PS
         JOIN Players P ON PS.PlayerId = P.PlayerId
         JOIN Teams T ON P.TeamId = T.TeamId
         JOIN Matches M  ON PS.MatchId = M.MatchId

    WHERE T.TeamId = 3
      AND Matches.MatchId = 1025
    GROUP BY P.Player_Name,
             PS.Bat_Runs
    ORDER BY Bat_Runs DESC
    ) AS Away;
```

*Edit: We now have an expected result set. I suspect that the `GROUP BY` isn't needed here. Why? Well the OP has no aggregation so it makes no sense for it to be there so I have removed it.*

*They state they don't have a relationship, but there is one, the relationship they want is on the ranking of the runs for both team. This therefore gives a query like:*

```
WITH Home AS(
    SELECT P.Player_Name AS Batsman,
           PS.Bat_Runs As Runs,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PS.Bat_Runs) AS RunsRank
    FROM PlayerScores PS
         JOIN Players P ON PS.PlayerId = P.PlayerId
         JOIN Teams T ON P.TeamId = T.TeamId
         JOIN Matches M  ON PS.MatchId = M.MatchId
    WHERE T.TeamId = 1
    AND M.MatchId = 1025),
Away AS (
    SELECT P.Player_Name AS Batsman,
           PS.Bat_Runs As Runs,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PS.Bat_Runs) AS RunsRank
    FROM PlayerScores PS
         JOIN Players P ON PS.PlayerId = P.PlayerId
         JOIN Teams T ON P.TeamId = T.TeamId
         JOIN Matches M  ON PS.MatchId = M.MatchId
    WHERE T.TeamId = 3
      AND Matches.MatchId = 1025
    )
SELECT H.Batsman AS HomeBatsMan,
       H.Runs AS HomeBatsManRuns,
       A.Batsman AS AwayBatsMan,
       A.Runs AS AwayBatsManRuns
FROM Home H
     JOIN Away A ON H.RunsRank = A.RunsRank
WHERE H.RunsRank <= 3;
```

Comment: it gives me required result up to some extend , but it gives me in the same list.

Comment: @FarazAhmedShaikh that's because, like the answer says, it was a complete guess. Now that you've provided your results, we can provide you with an answer.

Comment: @FarazAhmedShaikh ok, that *should* give you the results you want; if my guess on what your data looks like is correct.

Comment: Yes it working as per my requirement.. Thanks to you.. <3 (y)

Comment: You're welcome, @FarazAhmedShaikh. Please remember to mark it as the solution so that others with the same problem will know that it helped you resolve the problem.